# Button change with AJAX

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have created a system where you can visit a place and have all the code that allows for an entry to be posted to the database and deleted from the database on button click with ajax but i am struggling to work out how to make the button change with ajax when its clicked depending on whether the record exists or not. At the moment the button only changes if the page is refreshed albeit the AJAX code works for adding or deleting from the database. How would i get my buttons to change and respond to the if statement with AJAX? here is what i have so far:

Html:

```
@if(Auth::user()->visitors()->where('place_id', $place->id)->first())
      <a class="btn btn-visited visit"  data-id="{{ $place->id }}">I've Visited <i class="fas fa-check"></i></a>
       @else
      <a class="btn btn-not-visited visit"  data-id="{{ $place->id }}">Visited?</a>
@endif
```

AJAX JS:

```
var token = '{{ Session::token() }}';
var urlVisit = '{{ route('visitss') }}';

$('.visit').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: urlVisit,
        data: {
            place_id: $(event.target).data("id"),
            _token: token
        }
    }).done(function() {
        //
    });
});
```

php:

```
$place_id = $request['place_id'];
        $place = place::find($place_id);
        $visited = Auth::user()->visitors()->where('place_id', $place_id)->first();

    if($visited == null) {
                $visited = new Visit();
                $visited->user_id = Auth::user();
                $visited->place_id = $place->id;
                $visited->save();
                return null;
            }
        else{

          $visited->delete();
             return null;
        }
```

How do i get the buttons to respond with AJAX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blade is running in PHP, so your ajax call cannot respond to the if-statement unless you are fetching that blade file in the ajax request.

I also strongly recommend not doing your logic in the blade file. It doesn't follow MVC logic. Do it in the controller and pass it into the view.

Controller:

```
$visited = Auth::user()->visitors()->where('place_id', $place->id)->first():

return view('something')->with('visited', $visited);
```

Then, in your controller that responds to the Ajax call, return `true` instead of null. This will be a successful response and you can then use the jQuery `done()` method to swap out the text and classes of the button to mark it as visited!

Sample jQuery:

```
$('.btn.visit').removeClass('btn-not-visited').addClass('btn-visited').html('I\'ve Visited <i class="fas fa-check"></i>');
```

Comment: Any examples of the last bit you describe?

Comment: That kind of works, i just need to work out how to do that when the record exists in the database and how to change it back if it doesnt exist.

Comment: Ah. First, I recommend separation of concern. You are using one Ajax call to do two different things. Maybe consider making to separate calls. If you don't want to do this, return false instead of true when it doesn't exist. Then you can use JS in the success area of your Ajax call to determine what to do.

Comment: How would you recommend doing the false and true part? adding a new field to data calling it into the controller by request and setting it as true or false?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean.. Just decide on what false and true mean. For example, return true just after creating the visited model and return false after deleting it. Then in your `done()` method, have an if-statement that changes the classes and html differently depending on what the returned value is (of true or false).

Comment: if i do that it returns a 500 error due to the response not being a sting and being a boolean instead

Comment: K. Return your own two strings then instead of true or false. Then check off of that.

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the button on success from Ajax.

So Insert whatever you want to do in your success function

```
$('.visit').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: urlVisit,
        data: {
            place_id: $(event.target).data("id"),
            _token: token
        }
    }).done(function() {
        // add button change here
        // select the buttons I'd and manipulate e.g.
       $('#buttonID').html('change');
   });
});
```